# (C) How are the implementations of the stdlib functions stored and linked to in header files if the source code does not have to be provided directly?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, precompiled-headers

new to using C

Header files for libraries like stdlib do not contain the actual implementation code for the functions they provide access to. I understand that the actual source text for libraries like this aren't needed to compile, but **how does this work specifically?** **Are the implementation details for these libraries contained within the compiler?**

When you use a function like printf(), including the header file essentially pastes in code for the declaration of the function, but normally the implementation code would need to be available as well.
***What form is it stored in?*** (and where?) **Is this compiler specific**? **Would it be possible to write custom code and reference it in this way without modifying the behavior of the compiler?**

I've been searching around and found some info that is relevant but nothing specific. This could be related to not formulating the question well. Thanks.

Comment: You need to look up the concepts of linker, object files and libraries.

Comment: The linker is what actually extracts the needed functions from the library and added those functions to the executable.  The header file is (mostly) just to supply the prototypes for the function calls so the compiler will not error abort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you link a program, the compiler will implicitly add some extra libraries to your program:

```
$ ls
main.c
$ cc -c main.c
$ cc main.o
$ ls
main.c main.o a.out
```

You can discover the extra libraries a program uses with `ldd`.  Here, there are three libraries linked into the program, and I didn't ask for any of them:

```
$ ldd a.out
linux-vdso.so => (0x00...)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00...)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00...)
```

So, what happens if we link without these libraries?  That's easy enough, just use the linker (`ld`) directly, instead of calling it through `cc`.  When you use `ld`, it doesn't give you these extra libraries, so you get an error:

```
$ ld main.o
Undefined symbols:
  "_printf", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
```

The implementation for `printf()` is stored in the standard C library, which is usually just another library on your system... the only difference is that it gets automatically included into your program when you compile C.

You can use `nm` to find out what symbols are in a library, so I can use it to find `printf()` in `libc`:

```
$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so | grep printf
...
000000000004e4b0 T printf
...
```

So, now that we know that `libc` has `printf()`, we can use `-lc` to tell the linker to include `libc`, and that will get rid of the errors about `printf()` being missing:

```
$ ld main.o -lc
```

There might be some other bits missing, and that's why we use `cc` to link our programs instead of `ld`: `cc` gives us all the default libraries.

Comment: @indiv: What part? "When you link a program, you implicitly get some extra libraries (in addition to the ones you *explicitly specify*)

Comment: @indiv: You implicitly get `libc` linked to your program.  It's implicit, because I didn't tell the compiler to use `libc`: you would specify `-lc` to do that, and `-lc` is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Oh.. internal brain parser error.  When you link a program, there are additional libraries that get linked implicitly.  Got it.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile a file you only need to promise the compiler that you have certain functions and symbols. A function call is in the compiled into a `call [some_address]`

The compiler will compile each C-file into object files that just have place holders for calls to functions declared in the headers. That is `[some_address]` does not need to be known at this point.

A number of oject files can be collected into what is known as a library.

After that it is the linkers job to look through all object files and libraries it know of and find out what the real value of all unknown `[some_address]` is and translate the call to, e.g. `call 0x1234` if the particular function you are calling starts at `0x1234` (or it might be a relative offset from the current program pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Stdlib and other library functions are implemented in an object library.  A library is a collection of code that is linked with your program.  By default C programs are linked against the stdlib library, which is usually provided by the operating system.  Most modern operating systems use a dynamical linker.  That is, your program is not linked against the library until it is executed.  When it is being loaded, the linker-loader combines your code and the library code in your program's address space.  You code and then make a call to the printf() code that is located in that library.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a header file contains only a function prototype while the implementation is either in a separate source file **or a precompiled library** in the case of *stdlib* (and other libraries, both shipped with a compiler or available separately) the precompiled library gets linked at the end of the compilation process. (There's also a distinction between static and dynamic libraries, but I won't go into detail about that)

The implementation of standard libraries (which are shipped with a compiler) are usually compiler specific (there is a standard describing which functions have to be in a library, but the compiler programmer can decide how exactly he implements them) and it is (in theory) possible to exchange these libraries with some of your own without modifying the behaviour of the compiler (though not recommended as you would have to rewrite the entire library in order to ensure that all functions are contained).